# parse OpenCV frame between threads

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, opencv, visual-studio-2013

Hey I have a simple thread on Windows:

```
while (!MainThreadHasFinished) {
    cv::Mat frame = (cv::Mat)lpParameter;       //Casting try.
    cv::imshow("Camera image", (frame));        //Show Img in window
    printf("img printed");                      //print text to cmd

    if (cv::waitKey(1) == 27)                   // exit this loop when ESC was pressed
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Where the issue is that I cannot do `cv::imshow`, It does not seem like it is the casting to cv::Mat :)

I create the thread as:

```
DWORD thread_ID;
HANDLE handle_NumberCruncher = CreateThread( 
    NULL,                   // default security attributes
    0,                      // use default stack size  
    NumberCruncher,         // thread function name
    &frame,                 // argument to thread function 
    0,                      // use default creation flags 
    &thread_ID);            // returns the thread identifier
```

I have seen multiple references to casting on MSDN and Stack, but nothing for the image.

If this is not possible, then the question in general is how to parse data between threads. Where the idea is that some processing on the image could be done in the main thread and then parsing it on for some more advanced stuff not needed for every image. Without using globals. As the thread could be on a different processor, just as an example :)

Comment: threads without locks - pheww.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lpParameter` is a `void*` pointer. You have to cast it to `cv::Mat` pointer type first, i.e.:

```
DWORD WINAPI NumberCruncher( LPVOID lpParameter )
{
   while (!MainThreadHasFinished) {
      cv::Mat* frame = (cv::Mat*)lpParameter;     //Casting try.
      printf("img printed");                      //print text to cmd

      // Display image in the main thread
      // ...

      Sleep(1);
   }
   return 0;
}

DWORD thread_ID;
HANDLE handle_NumberCruncher = CreateThread( 
    NULL,                   // default security attributes
    0,                      // use default stack size  
    NumberCruncher,         // thread function name
    &frame,                 // argument to thread function 
    0,                      // use default creation flags 
    &thread_ID);            // returns the thread identifier
```

Or, if the thread does not need access to the original variable:

`cv::Mat value = *(cv::Mat*)lpParameter;`

---

p.s.:
GUI systems usually let you display things on the screen and get user input on the main thread. Try using `imshow` & `waitkey` from the main thread.

Comment: ahh damn-it I tried what you suggested but get the following error: Unhandled exception at 0x7648C42D in opencvTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0588FAF4. It comes when `cv::imshow` is called

Comment: GUI systems usually let you display things on the screen and get user input on the main thread. Try just using `imshow` & `waitKey` from the main thread.

Comment: That works fine. I tested you notion about the main thread should have the GUI application. But I am able to do `cv::Mat output = cv::Mat::zeros(120, 350, CV_8UC3);
  putText(output, "Hello World :)", cvPoint(15, 70), cv::FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3, cvScalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
  imshow("Output", output);` which would imply that the initial code should work if `frame` was passed correctly or?

Comment: `imshow` is not thread safe, so perform it just after the synchronization. Furthermore, you might need to initialize the visualization window before creating the thread with `cv::namedWindow("Output")`.